# How to run script in the package.json with zx?

Tags: node.js

I use zx to create a script .
and I run `yarn web:build`  in my zx.mjs script.
but it return errors:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'
```

why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I use node api(exec) to save this question. But I think it should be more directly and easy to use:

```
import { exec } from "child_process";
export default function runScript(script = "") {
  exec(script, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  });
}
```

and import this script in zx script:

```
import runScript from './runScript.mjs'
runScript(`yarn run web:build`);
```

it works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because it was removed by something that zx uses. Try installing the yarn/node package again, for node it's npm install worker_threads, or yarn, which is yarn add worker_threads.
It may also be that zx might reject the package, so try using it normally, not in your zx script.

Comment: why i can use yarn web:build directly but couldnt use it in my zx script

Comment: Sorry @radiorz, I'll add that.

Comment: my ```yarn web:build ```actually run ```vite build```